# passing arguments through flask in Python Jupyter notebook to conduct mathematical operations

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, flask, data-extraction

I want to return the addition of two numbers which are passed as parameters to a function using Flask in Python Jupyter notebook. My code is as below. I am getting the error as "URL Not Found"

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from flask import Flask

@app.route('/post/<int:a>,<int:b>')
def show_post(a,b):
    sum=a+b
    return 'Post %d' % sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 9000, app)
```

May I know how can I get the required result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the output, I was not printing the right URL in the browser earlier

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from flask import Flask

@app.route('/<int:num1>,<int:num2>')
def addition_of_numbers(num1,num2):
    sum=num1+num2
    return '%d' % sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 9000, app)
```

In the browser if let's say the numbers are 4 and 5:

```
http://localhost:9000/4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

A flask view function cannot return an `int`, it must return at least a `str`.

```
@app.route("/<int:a>,<int:b>")
def hello(a,b):
    return str(a + b)
```

Then open your browser at http://localhost:9000/1,2 in and it should display 3

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Any idea on how can we do this in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I found on Flask website that there is a way:
@app.route('/<int:num1>,<int:num2>')
def addition_of_numbers(num1,num2):

    sum=num1+num2
    return '%d' % sum